# Which weapons do force fields affect?

Tags: starcraft-2

I've been playing the SC2 "Star Battle" custom map, and have had a hard time understanding how the force field really works. From the [wiki](http://starbattle.wikia.com/wiki/Arbiter):

> Forcefields will block all enemy lasers and missiles within their area of effect.

Will force fields affect ultimate weapons? What about interceptor attacks or fighter attacks? I'm experimenting with a carrier-interceptor build and I want to know if I should target force-fielded enemies.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding of this description is that anything that shoots lasers or missiles at the force fielded units and is outside of the force field will be met with unsuccesful results. although seeing as interceptors get incredbly close to the unit before shooting it is possible that they might be able to rid of the pesky buggers

Answer (score -1):

Forcefields do not affects weapons in any kind. It only affects the movement of certain units. (massive units like Archons, Thors, Ultralisks etc. break forcefields). Because of the movement restriction you will find yourself unable to attack with your ground units (zerglings, zealots etc.) thus leaving them useless in the fight.

Comment: I am not asking about vanilla SC2, but about a custom map built on top of it. I've edited my question to clarify that.